# C++'s std::forward equivalent in Scala

Tags: c++, scala, templates

Is there an equivalent in Scala for C++'s `std::forward`?

For example, I'd like to create a code in Scala that would be similar to this C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Entity {
public:
    Entity(string author, int somethingElse): author(author), somethingElse(somethingElse) {
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    static Entity apply(Args&&... args) {
        return Entity(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    string author;
    int somethingElse;
};


int main() {
    Entity e = Entity::apply("hello", 123);
    return 0;                                                                               
}
```

So the main feature in this code is that when I change the constructor of `Entity` class, I don't have to maintain the same argument list for the `apply` method, because it's inferred automatically by the compiler. The types are also verified during compile time, and the types in the constructor can be different. They're not casted to anything else (i.e. they're not casted to `void*`).

In Scala, I'd like to create the code such as this:

```scala
import org.scalajs.dom

case class Entity(author: String, element: dom.Element) {

}

object Entity {                                              
  def apply(/* ??? */): Entity = {
    new Entity(/* ??? */)
  }
}
```

Comment: Scala compiler automatically implements `apply` with identical arguments to case class. `case class Entity(author: String, element: Int)` ... Identical: `Entity("a", 1)`, `Entity.apply("a", 1)`, `new Entity("a", 1)`. Is that's what are you looking for or do you want to abstract argument list from the type?

Comment: This really is a nice example of a super complex solution in another language, you simply get for free in Scala where this sort of thing just works out of the box.

Comment: @yǝsʞǝla I would like to know if I can use the same argument list in a method that is used in another method. Indeed the `apply` function is generated by the compiler automatically for case classes (I've missed that one), but in case I'd like to create a more complex `apply` function, I'll probably need to somehow override the default one, and the problem will come back. Well, unless I'm missing something! Full disclaimer: I'm a Scala newbie! (but you already know that I guess :D)